# Is there any difference in meaning between "call all of my friends" and "call around to all of my friends"?

Tags: difference, phrasal-verbs

Would you please tell me if there is any difference in meaning between *call all of my friends* and  *call around to all of my friends*? For example:

> I've **called** all of my friends to ask if anyone has that book.
>
> I've **called around to** all of my friends to ask if anyone has that book.

Are both perfectly natural?

Comment: You never show any research....

Answer (score -1, accepted):

In this particular context, the two sentences mean basically the same thing (at least in the US). But let me explain a possible slight difference.

First, note that you could simply say "I've called around to ask if anyone has that book." This sentence suggests that you've called several people, but it's obviously very vague as to who those people are.

In my opinion, when you use "around" in your second example, it somehow retains this element of vagueness, even though you've specified the people that you called - i.e., all your friends. If you literally mean that you called every friend of yours, the "around" is unnecessary. So maybe the use of "around" gives me the impression that "all my friends" is an exaggeration. As you know, we in the US are serial exaggerators. In any case, the effect is very slight, and perhaps imagined.

Comment: "in my opinion"...

Answer (score 0):

There's perhaps a difference in *method*.

> I've called all of my friends to ask if anyone has that book.

implies you phoned them.

> I've called around to all of my friends to ask if anyone has that book.

implies you visited their houses personally.

Comment: Also depends what side of the pond you're on. To "call around" in North America means phone a bunch of people. We almost never use "call" to mean visit, except with "call on", and even that's rare.

Comment: @gotube: Would you please tell me if "call" and "call around" mean the same thing to you in my sentence.

Comment: @DmytroO'Hope In that context, they're just about interchangeable. One possible difference is that "called around to" suggests there was **a list** to get through, whereas "called" alone does not suggest a list.